# Should a value be used for all attributes?

Tags: html

There are attributes in HTML that only specify a boolean value. These include `multiple`, `disabled`, `selected` etc.

In XHTML, due to the strict XML syntax, you must give the attributes a value. This is normally the name of the attribute.

```
<select multiple="multiple">
```

But HTML also supports just the name of the element.

```
<select multiple>
```

And, as seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zu5tejjb/), browsers (at least Firefox) also allow for other values with the same result.

```
<select multiple="yes">
```

Which one of these is the generally used one, or is there one? What is the official recommendation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes)

> A number of attributes are boolean attributes. The presence of a
>   boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the
>   absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>
> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string
>   or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's
>   canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.

So `multiple`, `multiple=multiple`, `multiple='multiple'` or `multiple="multiple"`. Nothing else (case insensitivity aside), even if browsers recover from the error.

I'd lean towards either the short (`multiple`) or the XML parser-friendly with the more conventional quotes (`multiple="multiple"`).